# PHP: $_SESSION can't be used more than once in a page?

Tags: php, list, session, while-loop, repeat

This may be a silly question and sorry for any confusing sentences.. I don't know if I can explain this issue well enough to make you understand, but `$_SESSION` seems unable to  be repeated more than once on a page.

```
session_start();
while (list($a, $b) = each($_SESSION['temp']))
  echo "<li>$a - $b</li>";
```

The above code is ok, but if I have `$_SESSION['temp']` on the same page as below, then it doesn't show anything...

```
session_start();
while (list($a, $b) = each($_SESSION['temp']))
  echo "<li>$a - $b</li>";
while (list($c, $d) = each($_SESSION['temp']))
  echo "<li>$c - $d</li>";                            /* <=== nothing shown :( */
```

To get the value from the `$_SESSION['temp'],` I need to give it a new name:

```
session_start();

$temp = $_SESSION['temp'];                            /* <== new name */
while (list($a, $b) = each($_SESSION['temp']))
  echo "<li>$a - $b</li>";
while (list($c, $d) = each($temp))
  echo "<li>$c - $d</li>";                            /* <=== now shown :) */
```

Can you tell me how come `$_SESSION['temp']` can't be used twice or more on the same page?
Is there any better way to get a value from `$_SESSION['temp']`?
Thank you.

Comment: @Conner, thank you for correcting my words.. much better now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php

Return the current key and value pair from an array and advance the array cursor.

After each() has executed, the array cursor will be left on the next element of the array, or past the last element if it hits the end of the array. You have to use `reset()` if you want to traverse the array again using each.

```
session_start();
while (list($a, $b) = each($_SESSION['temp']))
  echo "<li>$a - $b</li>";

reset($_SESSION);

while (list($c, $d) = each($_SESSION['temp']))
  echo "<li>$c - $d</li>";
```

Comment: I know there is similarity, but AFAIR foreach() does not require you to reset the array. See my answer for explanation what I really wanted.

Comment: I checked it and I was correct, foreach does not require resetting the pointer, see my answer for details.

Comment: Thank you, so it can be replaced as below?
    foreach ($_SESSION['temp'] as $a => $b) echo "<li>$a - $b</li>";

Comment: @chloe, Yes, I so sorry: each return array($key, $value)

Comment: @chloe use foreach ($_SESSION['temp'] as $a => $b) { // do what you wanted with each item };  It's good way

Comment: @Sergey Thank you for the update and my code looks much nicer :)

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is correct, but there is better way:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['temp'] as $a => $b) {
    // do what you wanted with each item
};
// repeat the code here
```

foreach loop does not require resetting after usage, so it is easier to use (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> When foreach first starts executing, the internal array pointer is automatically reset to the first element of the array. This means that you do not need to call reset() before a foreach loop.

Comment: Sorry, I mistake: each return array($key, $value) for each element in array. Well your answer will be: `foreach ($_SESSION['temp'] as $a => $b) {
    // do what you wanted with each item
};
`